# $\arctan{x}=\arccos{2x}.$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

First, let's determine some domains. By definition, it follows that $\arccos:[-1,1]\rightarrow[0,\pi]$ and $\arctan:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Since the domain of $\arctan$ is the entire reals, the restricting factor here should be the domain of arccos. This means that $2x\in[-1,1]\Rightarrow x\in\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

I now take cosine of both sides and get $$\cos{(\arctan{x})}=\cos{(\arccos{2x})}=2x.$$

I use the formular $\cos{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2{a}}},$ and rewrite as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2{(\arctan{x})}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=2x.$$

Squaring both sides, simplifying and setting $t=x^2$ gives the quadratic equation

$$t^2+t-\frac{1}{4}=0\Longleftrightarrow \left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    t_1 & = & -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} <0 \\
    t_2 & = & -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} >0\\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Since $t_1<0$, it is a false root since a square of a real number $x$ can not become a negative real number $t$. So the final two roots in terms of $x$ are

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcr}
    x_1 & = & +\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)} \\
    x_2 & = & -\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}-1)} \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Clearly, both $x_1,x_2\in[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$. Only $x_1$ is correct however. I did something wrong setting up the domain didin't I? I have a feeling that the correct domain for the solutions is $[0,\frac{1}{2}],$ I don't know how to see it.

Comment: hint: $\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}>0}$

Comment: Yes, it's positive for all $x$:es, but RHS is only positive for $x_1$. But how can one in the begining determine the confines of $x$ by looking at the respective domains and then combining them.

Comment: Your domain must be $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\cap\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]=\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right]$

Comment: squaring is not an injective function so you cannot presume that the domain analysis will hold

Comment: $\arccos$ in the RHS has values in $[0,\pi]$ so the LHS must be positive thus $0\le x \le \dfrac{1}{2}$ is the right domain of the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \in \left[\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right]$ we have $\arctan x \in \left[-\arctan\frac{1}{2}, \arctan\frac{1}{2}\right] \subseteq \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, so $\cos(\arctan x) \ge 0$.

So $\cos(\arctan x) = 2x$ implies $x \geq 0$, which discards the negative solution $x_2$.

Comment: Why does it follow that $\arctan x \in \left[-\arctan\frac{1}{2}, \arctan\frac{1}{2}\right] \subseteq \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ ?

Comment: @Parseval $\arctan$ is strictly increasing so  $$\arctan \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right]
\subseteq \left[\arctan\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right), \arctan \frac{1}{2}\right] = \left[-\arctan\frac{1}{2}, \arctan\frac{1}{2}\right]$$ From continuity of $\arctan$ now follows that $\arctan \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right] =  \left[-\arctan\frac{1}{2}, \arctan\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

Comment: Now I noticed that in fact we don't even need that since we automatically have $\arctan x \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, so $\cos(\arctan x) \ge 0$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arctan x=\arccos(2x)=u$

Using the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of  Principal values of Inverse trigonometric functions,

$-\dfrac\pi2\le u\le\dfrac\pi2,0\le u\le\pi\implies0\le u\le\dfrac\pi2\implies x\ge0$

We have $x=\tan u,2x=\cos u$

$$\dfrac1{(2x)^2}-x^2=1\implies4x^4+4x^2-1=0$$

$$\implies x^2=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt2}2$$

For real $x,$

$$x^2=\dfrac{\sqrt2-1}2$$

and we know $x\ge0$